# array of prefix sums of the given array. JavaScript,

Tags: javascript, arrays, prefix

I have checked few solutions, but I could not find one for me.
I have problem with creating new array with sum of prefixes for example:
arr = [1,2,3,4,5] should give newarr = [1,3,6,10,15]
My code works, but only for one digit (e.g. 3 will give 6).
I wanted to use .map or forEach.

```
in131 = document.getElementById('in131num');
ans131 = document.getElementById('answer131');
document.querySelector('#btn131').addEventListener('click', () => {
   const arr131 = in131.value;
   arr131.split(' ');
   const new131 = [];

   for (let i = 1; i <= arr131; i++) {
       new131.push(i);
   }
   console.log(
       new131.reduce((a, b) => {
           return a + b;
       })
   );
   ans131.textContent = new131.reduce((a, b) => {
       return a + b;
   });

   console.log(
       new131.forEach((x) =>
           x.reduce((a, b) => {
               return a + b;
           })
       )
   );
});
```

how to use .reduce on .map?
what could be other solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Map

Basic solution map to create a new result Array and inside of map use a loop to build the sum.

```js
    let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

    const result = arr.map((val, index) => {
    let sum = 0;
    
    for(let i = 0; i < index+1 ; i++){
    sum += arr[i];
    }
    return sum;
    });

    console.log(result);
```

#### Loop + Reduce

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
let resultArr = [];
for(let i = 1; i < arr.length+1; i++){
let tempArr = arr.slice(0, i, arr);
const result = tempArr.reduce((acc, val) => {
     acc += val;
     return acc;
     }, 0)
     resultArr.push(result);
    }


 console.log(resultArr);
```

Snippet from the commentarys

```js
let ans131 = document.getElementById("answer131")

document.querySelector("#btn131").addEventListener("click", () => {
  let splitted = document.getElementById("in131num").value.split(",");
  let valasnumber = splitted.map((val) => {
    return Number(val);
  })
  console.log(valasnumber);
  const prefix = valasnumber.map((val, index) => {
    let sum = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < index + 1; i++) {
      sum += valasnumber[i];
    }
    return sum;
  })
  console.log(prefix)

})
```

```html
<input type="text" id="in131num"></input>
<button id="btn131"></button>
```

Comment: Thank you, I like first option, everything works of course. But I have a problem with storing multiple numbers from one input. Your version is based on already defined array: let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
Problem starts when user is typing more than one number. I tried to push input.value to new arr and the results are wrong (it pushes only first number). console.log shows one number without array. Map wont start because arr is not defined. 
 Do you know how to solve this?

Comment: check if input.value is actually a number with typeof, can you share your example code? It s hard to say without the code

Comment: Thanks.that input if is a single number return Number, but if I will add two or more numbers, it return NaN. 
My code:
```
in131 = document.getElementById("in131num")
  ans131 = document.getElementById("answer131") 
document.querySelector("#btn131").addEventListener("click", () =>{
const arr131 = [];

arr131.push(Number(in131.value))
   console.log(arr131)

const prefix =arr131.map((val, index) => {
  let sum=0;
  for (let i=1; i< index + 1; i++ ){
    sum+=arr131[i];
  }
  return sum;
} ) 
console.log(prefix)
})
```

Comment: you have to run from i = 0
I have updated my answer with your snippet

Comment: thanks, I've changed that but console.log shows NaN when I type more than one number...

Comment: Really? NaN probably because you acces in array[i] an element which not exist in the array so undefined. But in the snippet above which I added when I type in two numbers it work as expected. Can you do a jsfiddle with your code or can tell me what is wrong with my snippet above

Comment: I tried 'Snippet from the commentarys' jsfiddle. I see your point. You used two inputs, but when I type 2 and 5 to first and second input, it returns 2 and 7 instead of: 3 and 15. 
 I am looking for solution for one input where user can type for example: 2 3 4 5. So user can type all array straight in at once and gets an output: 3 6 10 15. 
 thank you for interest.

Comment: 2 and 7 is correct, 2 at first element 2+5 at second element.
Okay I understand.

Comment: Have updated my answer, in the last snippet you can type in comma seperated values

Comment: I dont reallu undrestant that code is still adding up the [i] instead of adding up prefixes. 
Your first solution: 
 `let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

    const result = arr.map((val, index) => {
    let sum = 0;
    
    for(let i = 0; i < index+1 ; i++){
    sum += arr[i];
    }
    return sum;
    });

    console.log(result);
`
and that solution is giving the right prefixes. But last jsfiddle with user inputs and the same function is working wrong...

Comment: No it isn't? type in 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 it is the same as in the first snippet @konrad

Comment: Thank you very much, you showed ma a lot useful staff, e.g. user input spliting in one line. Previously Iused to create const input and then const arr = input.split. I didnt know we can wrire it immediately - :) 
 I understood the task wrong, I was thinking prefixes are all numbers contain one number, e.g: input 10, 11 should give 55 and 61 (10 is prefixed like:  1+2+3+4.....+10 = 55). Sorry for confusing. my fault

Comment: You're welcome :) If you think this was helpful mark it as accepted the button below up / down voting

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using `split` on a string, you have an array of strings, not numbers

```
new131.reduce((p,c) => p + parseInt(c, 10), 0)
```